# Android: How to request inherited field via Facebook Graph API

Tags: android, facebook

In the below link it says video.watches has an inherited field named [image], how can I modify below code to request it (Receive it)?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/video.watches

```
Bundle params.putString("fields", "data{image}");
```

Comment: Are you sure there's a value for 'image' present on the object you're reading? have you debugged by making the same call directly or via a tool like the Graph API Explorer?

Comment: @lgy According to the link above there should be "image" field, but using debugging there is no returned "image" field even when I revemoved "fields" parameter

Comment: I mean, how can you be sure there's a value present for 'image' for the specific action you're reading? if there's no value the field isn't returned